# Can you help identify what set these parts belong to?

Tags: set-identification

Can you help identify what set these parts belong to?
There is two blue octagonal parts, two red parts,
dark grays, blacks and bananas.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't match everything, but it looks a lot like [this](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70008-1) set.

Answer (score 3):

Those  [Plate, Modified 10 x 10 Octagonal with 6 x 6 Open Center](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6063&name=Plate,%20Modified%2010%20x%2010%20Octagonal%20with%206%20x%206%20Open%20Center&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&C=153&O=%7B%22color%22:%22153%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) only come in dark azure (and doesn't even exist in any other bluish colour) in two sets; only one of them also has [Yellow Banana](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33085&idColor=3), and that is the set that Heartspring already has pointed at in [a comment](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18108/can-you-help-identify-what-set-these-parts-belong-to#comment23705_18108): namely  [Gorzan's Gorilla Striker](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70008-1#T=I).